# Adding one vector as column and one as row to a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am looking to add two vector to get a matrix-style object, which looks something

[image: Matrix]

I am doing it with the following code:

```
a <- c (1:5, 8, 8 + 0:5)
a <- unique(a)
a <- sort (a)
a
b <- c ( "aa", "ba", "cz", "pp")
b
```

But don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: Please share expected output, but not as a picture.

Comment: `matrix(NA, length(b), length(a), dimnames = list(b, a))` maybe?

Comment: Do you need an empty data frame with b and a as row and column names?

Comment: @RonakShah, yeah that would be a possibility. The only thing is I need to be able to access them as I have another data.frame, with rows containing one of the elements of a and one from b. And if any combination of the two is present, I need to put a "1" in the matrix drawn in the picture above.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, that does work. Thank so much!